# stop a 2d array at a random position

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have written a program in which a 2d array should loop until a random position. The problem is that some values are not transfered/registrated.
In addition to that, the 2nd array isnt random. It gets 0 all time.
And sometimes it doesnt even check the for-loop or just prints out some loops mltiple times

```
     int value1 = 777; //just to check if the value has updated
        int value2 = 777;
        int value3 = 777;
    
        int[][] wert = { { 0, 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 0, 2 }, { 0, 3 }, { 0, 4 }, { 0, 5 }, { 0, 6 }, { 0, 7 },
                { 0, 8 }, { 0, 9 },
                { 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 1, 3 }, { 1, 4 }, { 1, 5 }, { 1, 6 }, { 1, 7 },
                { 1, 8 }, { 1, 9 },
                { 2, 0 }, { 2, 1 }, { 2, 2 }, { 2, 3 }, { 2, 4 }, { 2, 5 }, { 2, 6 }, { 2, 7 },
                { 2, 8 }, { 2, 9 },
                { 3, 0 }, { 3, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 3, 3 }, { 3, 4 }, { 3, 5 }, { 3, 6 }, { 3, 7 },
                { 3, 8 }, { 3, 9 },
                { 4, 0 }, { 4, 1 }, { 4, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 4, 4 }, { 4, 5 }, { 4, 6 }, { 4, 7 },
                { 4, 8 }, { 4, 9 },
                { 5, 0 }, { 5, 1 }, { 5, 2 }, { 5, 3 }, { 5, 4 }, { 5, 5 }, { 5, 6 }, { 5, 7 },
                { 5, 8 }, { 5, 9 },
                { 6, 0 }, { 6, 1 }, { 6, 2 }, { 6, 3 }, { 6, 4 }, { 6, 5 }, { 6, 6 }, { 6, 7 },
                { 6, 8 }, { 6, 9 },
                { 7, 0 }, { 7, 1 }, { 7, 2 }, { 7, 3 }, { 7, 4 }, { 7, 5 }, { 7, 6 }, { 7, 7 },
                { 7, 8 }, { 7, 9 },
                { 8, 0 }, { 8, 1 }, { 8, 2 }, { 8, 3 }, { 8, 4 }, { 8, 5 }, { 8, 6 }, { 8, 7 },
                { 8, 8 }, { 8, 9 },
                { 9, 0 }, { 9, 1 }, { 9, 2 }, { 9, 3 }, { 9, 4 }, { 9, 5 }, { 9, 6 }, { 9, 7 },
                { 9, 8 }, { 9, 9 }, }; //2d array
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = rand.nextInt(200); i <= 100; i = rand.nextInt(200)) //random pos at the 1st array
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < rand.nextInt(2); j++) //random pos at the 2nd array
            {
                value1 = wert[i][j];
                System.out.println("i: " + i);
                System.out.println("j: " + j);
                 System.out.println("value1 " + value1);
                 System.out.println("  ");
            }
        }
        for (int i = rand.nextInt(200); i <= 100; i = rand.nextInt(200)) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rand.nextInt(2); j++) {
                value2 = wert[i][j];
                System.out.println("i: " + i);
                System.out.println("j: " + j);
                 System.out.println("value2 " + value2);
                 System.out.println("  ");
            }
        }

        for (int i = rand.nextInt(200); i <= 100; i = rand.nextInt(200)) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rand.nextInt(2); j++) {
                value3 = wert[i][j];
                System.out.println("i: " + i);
                System.out.println("j: " + j);
                 System.out.println("value3 " + value3 );
                 System.out.println("  ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(value1 + " " + value2 + " " + value3); //outprinting the values
        Thread.sleep(300);
```

Comment: `int i = rand.nextInt(200); i <= 100;` -> nothing will happen if you roll >100. Also, `int j = 0; j < rand.nextInt(2)` you might reassing the value multiple times instead of just once

Comment: thank you really much, but it doesnt work either

Comment: Might I ask what you intent with this "looping" to get a random value at all? Running a loop and stopping it at a random time will have no advantages over just getting a random value directly like `wert[rand.nextInt(wert.length)][rand.nextInt(2)]`

Comment: As @OHGODSPIDERS said, remove the loops and only assign `int i = rand.nextInt(wert.length);` and `int j = rand.nextInt(2);` for each value (without `int` keyword for the calls afterwards)

Comment: And its a way to get more random random numbers